# retrofit return HTTP 422 in the github user search url

Tags: android, api, http, github, retrofit

I ran this URL in the browser and it returns the correct values:
[enter link description here](https://api.github.com/search/users?q=%22%22)

but when I run this URL in the retrofit I get HTTP 422 error
how can I fix it?

```
  @Headers("Authorization: token MY_TOKEN")
    @GET("search/users")
    suspend fun searchUser(
            @Query("q") user: String? = "",
            @Query("page") page: Int = 1
    ): SearchUserEntity
```

I think this problem is happened when I pass "" to query. But it working I the browser. How can I fix the ""

Comment: hi, could it be the content type? https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/696

Comment: I made the correct model for this response

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET("search/users")
suspend fun searchProfilesSuspend(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Query("q") query: String): ProfileSearchResults
```

Everything seems to be correct, here is a snippet from my program, I myself recently studied coroutines and rewrote my project using them.

Have you looked at the additional information that the server returns along with the error code?
Maybe the number of requests has expired, there is a limit like 60 per hour if you are unauthorized.

[Here GithubSearcher](https://github.com/kirkaDev/GithubSearcher/tree/make-mvp-architecture/app/src/main/java/com/desiredsoftware/githubsearcher) you may see how it was implemented and several other requests.

Comment: If I pass "s" for search query everything is correct but I want to load users for empty string query

Comment: The problem is related to search empty strings ("") but I don't know how can I fix it